# python Using a dictionary to plot a decision tree (not using sci kit or graphviz)

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib, decision-tree

Does anyone know how to plot a dictionary to a decision tree in Python? It is a manual entry so i'm not interested in sci kit or graphviz.

I've tried pyplot but that doesn't seem to work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi, could you post your code? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here

[Dictionary object to decision tree in Pydot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13688410/dictionary-object-to-decision-tree-in-pydot)

For Python 3 change:
`for k,v in node.iteritems():` 
to 
`for k,v in node.items()`